# How to not connect to service when testing with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, testing, jhipster, kurento

I have an application built with JHipster which contains several tests.
I created a simple configuration class that instantiate a bean connected to an external service as such :

```
@Configuration
public class KurentoConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "kurentoClient")
    public KurentoClient getKurentoClient(@Autowired ApplicationProperties applicationProperties) {
        return KurentoClient.create(applicationProperties.getKurento().getWsUrl());
    }
}
```

But as you would guess, this code crash during testing because the external service is not up but this code is still run during application context loading.

So I need to create a "stateless" version of this bean to be used during testing.

Here is a simple example of a test that fail because of my configuration :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Face2FaceApp.class)
public class LogsResourceIntTest {

    private MockMvc restLogsMockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        LogsResource logsResource = new LogsResource();
        this.restLogsMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(logsResource)
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllLogs()throws Exception {
        restLogsMockMvc.perform(get("/management/logs"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE));
    }
}
```

What is the solution to make this bean not highly dependent of an external service during unit testing ?

Comment: You shoud try using a MockMvcBuilders that will help you build a mock from the actual service like you did, and in addition use some dataset to have an in-memory built-in database for your tests, which is a part of the Spring DBUnit testing framework

Comment: Where's KuretoClient used? Where and how it is injected? Shouldn't the ApplicationProperties be injected into KuretoClient? I don't see a benefit of having an additional type.

Comment: @slowy the instance of KurentoClient is being used on a WebSocket handler. Also KurentoClient is an external library so I can't inject it inside :/

Comment: @AnthonyGranger: You can easily do that ;). Just define an empty interface and write a _learning test_. That way you test your _expected behavior_, you can run that test after an upgrade of the system, _and_ you can exchange that library with another external system. And since you have written an interface, you can then provide two different spring contexts, one for test, one for production... the real implementation just delegates to the KuretoClient.

Comment: @slowy tank you for your answer :) but, how can I tell Spring to use my mocked implementation in test environment and real implementation otherwise ?

Comment: Well, for the test case we use @ContextConfiguration, but that's an older version of spring. For the production, you shouldn't have to change anything. But: I think you can configure n spring contexts, so you can have a 'base context' and an 'additional context', but not sure what the best practices are, we dynamically load all spring configuration files during the boot of our app, so the test-context is not included...

Comment: Well, my question is maybe not well written, but the problem you are talking about is, indeed, my main question. I used to configuration my application using .xml in old Spring version but today I try to use @Configuration. Also, this service should always stay mocked for UnitTesting as it will try to connect to an external server during application context loading...

Comment: To be honest, I try not to use spring IoC at all for unit testing, because of several reason: It gives me complete control about my objects within a class and is therefore much easier to write/read (imo). Having spring in your tests, does test the spring wiring implicitly, which is not exactly the definition of unit testing, and: It _does_ load the spring context, when I want to run a test case. In our app, that's about 30 seconds, and the test runs in millis. That's pretty frustrating, if you just want to test 10 lines of code... but not sure if it's possible to do that in spring boot :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141373/discussion-between-anthony-granger-and-slowy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of everyone here, I managed to solve this problem :

- I created an interface of KurentoClient and implemented a proxy that call KurentoClient methods
- My "normal" @Bean kurentoClient returns the implemented proxy
- I writed a @TestConfiguration (`UnitTestConfiguration`) and added a @Bean with the same signature as the one crated above but this one returns mockito's `mock(KurentoClient.class)`
- I created a class `TestBase` that every test class extends and which

contains

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = UnitTestConfiguration.class)
public class TestBase {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MockBean annotation in your test to replace your existing bean :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Face2FaceApp.class)
public class LogsResourceIntTest {

    @MockBean
    private KurentoClient kurentoClient;

    private MockMvc restLogsMockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        LogsResource logsResource = new LogsResource();
        this.restLogsMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(logsResource)
            .build();
        given(kurentoClient.someCall()).willReturn("mock");
    }
    ....
}
```

Here is the Spring Boot documentation :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: Thank you, but I do not use this service directly into my tests. It is loaded at startup and that's what cause the crash (external server is not running)

Comment: Ok I see, in this case I would mock the static method KurentoClient.create with powermock by example '@PrepareForTest(KurentoClient.class)' ... '

Comment: Or configure a test profil on the @Configuration bean